# Filling objects into a container: it's taking a while

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I tried making small objects fall into a container in Cycles, but by doing so when hitting the Animation Player feature, it just seems to take a while and like a long time. Is this normal in Blender? If there is a problem on the other hand, is there a way to make it go faster when making them fall into the container?

Answer (score 1):

What are your computer's specifications? Generally, it's pretty common since the physics calculations require extensive computation. You should bake your animations so you can play it a bit faster. More info https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html